# Selecting globally distinct values from multiple set

Tags: algorithm

I have N lists containing various numbers of objects and for each list a number X of required distinct values.

An simple example:

```
List1 = [ 1,2,3,4 ] : 2
List2 = [ 2,3,4 ] : 1
List3 = [ 1,2,4 ] : 1
```

Here one solution is to select 1 and 2 from List1, 3 from List2 and 4 from List3

But if the problem looks like this, there is no solutions

```
List1 = [ 1,2,3,4 ] : 2
List2 = [ 2,3,4 ] : 2
List3 = [ 1,2,4 ] : 1
```

So, the brute force solution to this problem is to select the required numbers of objects from the first list, then select the required numbers from the second list where the selected cannot be in the previous selected. If this fails, select other objects from the first list and so forth.

This, however, is not efficient and I might end up trying all combinations before I find a solution, if any.

So, is there any other way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem can be restated in terms of a flow network, and solved using a number of [maximum flow algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_flow_problem):

- Add a source vertex S
- Add a vertex G<sub>*i*</sub> for each of the sets
- Add an edge from S to G<sub>*i*</sub> with the capacity equal to the number of items to be selected
- Add a vertex N<sub>*i*</sub> for each distinct number in the *union* of all sets
- Add an edge with capacity 1 between each G<sub>*i*</sub> and N<sub>*i*</sub> where the set contains the number
- Add a sink vertex T
- Add an edge with capacity 1 between each N<sub>*i*</sub> and T

Here is how the flow network for your problem would look:

[image: Flow Network]

If the max flow algorithm does not produce a flow equal to the total required distinct numbers, the problem cannot be solved. Otherwise, use capacity assignments produced by the algorithm for edges between G<sub>*i*</sub> and N<sub>*i*</sub> to decide which numbers to take from each set.

Comment: It is seldom to see this great answers. I am implementing it as we speak with a smile on my face!

Comment: @plazm Wow, you coded up a working max flow in under forty minutes? That's impressive! You are welcome!

Comment: No, as any good programmer I find a library that has done it already! So I only utilized that library and made my project make the network. Do you have any comments on the FordFulkerson algorithm?

Comment: @plazm I think Ford-Fulkerson is fine for your problem, because you have integral capacities, and the value of max flow has a well-defined upper limit.

Comment: I was thinking the same, and as far as I understand the problem with it not finding a solution and running forever is only on circular networks, which I do not have - Am I correct?

Comment: @plazm Yes, you are correct. The algorithm is going to terminate for your graph.